# Force x-axis labels for one facet in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I am plotting data by country and each county has a different range of years with data so I'm using `free_x` in `facet_wrap (x-axis = year)`. One country (see Congo in attached image) ends up with years as decimals. Is there a way to force integers on the `x-axis` or manually edit the `x-axis` for a single facet?

```
data %>% 
  filter (Filter > 3 & Region == "Africa") %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = year,
                       y = ln_P,
                       group = country)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "glm", formula =  y ~ poly(x,2), se=FALSE, 
              aes(weight=N), color = "grey")+
  geom_point(aes(shape = Source), size = 2) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(text = element_text(family = "Times New Roman"), 
        legend.direction = "vertical",
        legend.position = c(0.8, 0.08), 
        legend.title = element_text(face="bold"), 
        strip.text = element_text(face="bold"),
        axis.text = element_text(color = "black")) +
  labs(y = "ln(P/100-P)", x = "Year") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "ln(P/100-P)", breaks = c(-6, -4, -2, 0)) +
  facet_wrap(~country, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

Comment: Is the `year` variable formatted as a date? Because then the labels for years are chosen slightly more wisely by ggplot.

Answer (score 1):

Without data, it’s difficult to work out an answer: 
I would try this.

1) Install `scales`, a very handy package for scaling, if you haven't done this before.

2) Assume your above `ggplot` graph named `p`:

```
p + scale_x_continuous(
   labels = scales::number_format(accuracy = 1))
```

If still not working, change your `date` (date class) into year:

```
data <- data %>% mutate(year = year(date))
```

Try 2) again, hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Formatting `year` as a date solved the problem. Thank you!

```
data %>% 
  filter (Filter>3 & Region == "Africa") %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = as.Date(as.character(year), "%Y"),
                   y = ln_P,
                   group = country)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "glm",formula =  y ~ poly(x,2), se=FALSE, aes(weight=N), color 
  = "grey")+
  geom_point(aes(shape = Source), size = 2) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(text = element_text(family = "Times New Roman"), 
        legend.direction = "vertical",
        legend.position = c(0.8, 0.08), 
        legend.title = element_text(face="bold"), 
        strip.text = element_text(face="bold"),
        axis.text = element_text(color = "black")) +
  labs(y = "ln(P/100-P)", x = "Year") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "ln(P/100-P)", breaks = c(-6, -4, -2, 0)) +
  facet_wrap(~country,scales = "free_x")
```